# would a discussion concerning my emacs fingers growing a bit stiffer be appropriate?

Tags: discussion, support

I've been an emacs user for many years. The last couple of weeks I've noticed my fingers loosing their "fluidity" and feeling a bit stiffer (resulting in a lower keys per minute count and more mistakes). I would like to ask whether this is alarming and what I should consider as possible remedies (e.g. keyboard, room temperature, diet, finger exercises, rest, etc.).

Comment: Maybe I've misunderstood the use of 'meta'. Isn't this the place to ask which questions are appropriate? Or should there be a meta-meta as well? why the downvote?

Comment: Meta works differently; you don't gain or lose reputation here. Downvotes simply mean people do not agree with what you're saying.

Comment: Downvotes on Meta have a different meaning than downvotes on the main site. Downvotes on meta mean "I disagree with this question" or "I think this is a *bad question*". But: you don't lose reputation points for downvotes on meta, and you don't risk having your account banned from meta, as long as your posts aren't deliberate trolling or anything of the sort. In short, don't take meta downvotes personally. They are very, very unlikely to have any negative effect on your account status.

Comment: Votes on meta usually indicate disagreement with the point raised in your question. In this case it is probably an indication that someone does not believe that your question is on-topic for our site.

Comment: This sounds like a medical question. I would ask a doctor, not a bunch of IT guys.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of course this is off-topic. Your fingers are not a part of a computer, nor are they software. You could ask this on Quora or maybe chat, but I don't think any existing SE site would field such a question based on their topicality rules.

Honestly, when I first read this question, I thought that maybe it was a joke. If it is a joke, ha-ha, you got me. But if you were being serious, then I just want to make it clear that asking how to make your fingers nimbler is definitely not topical for Super User.

*Edit:* Actually, it *might* be topical on [Fitness.SE](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/), though I would recommend posting a meta Q there before asking, because I'm really not sure. I've never asked a question on Fitness.SE before, and I haven't even joined their site. But based on a quick scan of their FAQ, it looks like this question could at least be within the general topic realm of what their site is about.

You would really have to remove the whole bit about emacs, though, and make the question generically about how one would go about making their fingers more dexterous for rapid keyboarding.

[See Here](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/19212/how-to-train-the-muscles-of-fingers) -- it looks like this question may have already been asked (or something very close to it) on Fitness.SE, and it wasn't closed. In fact, it has +1 upvotes. There may not be a lot of *interest* in this particular topic there, but at least the type of question is accepted by their community.

Answer (score 1):

I disagree that a question like that would generally be off-topic for Super User.

We even have [rsi](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/rsi) for "Questions relating to Repetitive Strain Injury", which is very much on-topic for our site as it can be categorized under interaction with computer hardware.

However, if you have a medical issue, you should talk to a physician, not computer geeks.

Comment: Haha....Dr. Geek to the rescue!!!!